# Django/Play Framework: Clarify situation with HTTP chunking/streaming

Tags: python, django, http, playback

Currently, I am new to a project that uses the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) for a web application backend.

For a specific REST endpoint we have to return a dynamically generated CSV file. To not hold the file in memory as a whole and to improve the TTFM (Time To First Byte) we thought about generating the file "on the fly" and returning those chunks immediately to the user.

Because I have some knowledge in Django, I knew there's the [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects) which is exactly for the use case I described above. So I searched if there's something equivalent in the Play Framework and discovered [`Chunked responses`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaStream#Chunked-responses). There they say it's using the "Chunked transfer encoding" mechanism provided by HTTP 1.1.

That leads me to the following questions:

1. Is both Django's `StreamingHttpResponse` and Play's `Chunked response` using the same mechanism in the background (like HTTP chunked transfer encoding) or do they use different techniques? [This blog post](https://andrewbrookins.com/django/how-does-djangos-streaminghttpresponse-work-exactly/) makes me guess they're using both the same mechanism in the background.
2. Assuming both are using the HTTP Chunked transfer encoding. What happens if my backend uses this, but HTTP 2.0 is supported and a compatible browser makes a HTTP 2.0 request?